# Apache2 sigterm crash on debian

Tags: apache, debian, sigterm

I have an issue with my debian server. 
I have a website hosted on an apache2 but 2 times per day, apache crash and my website is not accessible. 
I have looked log files and I haven't a lot of information. 
Here are my logs :

access.log

> 13.235.52.55:443  - - [24/May/2018:10:05:51 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13244 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
>   13.235.52.55:443  - - [24/May/2018:10:05:52 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13309 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
>   13.235.52.55:443  - - [24/May/2018:10:05:52 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13309 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
>   13.235.52.55:443  - - [24/May/2018:10:05:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13309 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
>   13.235.52.55:443  - - [24/May/2018:10:05:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13309 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"

error.log

> [Thu May 24 08:00:31.698217 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3544] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Thu May 24 08:00:31.698270 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3544] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Thu May 24 12:17:43.064962 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3544] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   [Thu May 24 12:17:46.968823 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4518] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Thu May 24 12:17:46.968889 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4518] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Thu May 24 12:17:47.011670 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4518] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Generally, apache crash at 12:17PM and 00:17AM

I have already check for a DoS attack, but I have not enough access in the access.log

Finally, I have found the following in my phperror log

> [24-May-2018 13:39:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 14:09:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 14:39:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 15:09:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 15:39:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 16:04:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   [24-May-2018 16:09:01 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

if someone can help me.. :-)

Thank you !

EDIT :
This is my journalctl when apache crashs
[journalctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wmgN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i've found where was the problem.

It was due to Certbot. I had 2 domains not used for a long time and the SSL certificates was expirated. I have remove these certificates and my apache is currently running for 1 day and 13 hours.

If this solution can help someone.. ;)